# How to set background color in Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


#from kivy.config import Config
#Config.set('graphics','fullscreen','auto')

sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())

class myGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class secondScreen(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(secondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols=1
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Second Screen'))
        self.btn1 = Button(text='Home')
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.btn1.bind(on_release=self.page1Func)


    def page1Func(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'page1'

class HomeScreen(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=[1,0,0,1])
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)


        self.cols=1
        self.add_widget(Label(text='[color=ec6135]Carloman Systems[/color]',font_size=50, markup=True))

        self.layout_name=myGridLayout(spacing=50,padding=[50 , 0 , 50 , -50])

        self.add_widget(self.layout_name)



        self.layout_name.cols=3

        self.btn1=Button(background_normal='./image-dark.png',
                         background_down='./image.png')
        self.layout_name.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.btn1.bind(on_release = self.page2Func)

        self.btn2=Button(background_normal='./image.png',
                         background_down='./image-dark.png')
        self.layout_name.add_widget(self.btn2)

        self.btn3=Button(background_normal='./image.png',
                         background_down='./image-dark.png')
        self.layout_name.add_widget(self.btn3)

        self.names_panel=myGridLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.names_panel)
        self.names_panel.cols=3

        self.names_panel.add_widget(Label(text='btn1', font_size=30))
        self.names_panel.add_widget(Label(text='btn2', font_size=30))
        self.names_panel.add_widget(Label(text='btn3', font_size=30))


    def page2Func(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'page2'
        #self.popup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=Label(text='Hello world'), auto_dismiss=False)


sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='page1'))
sm.add_widget(secondScreen(name='page2'))
sm.current='page1'

class MainScreen(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainScreen().run()
```

I am using this code for my GUI.
and i am using this code for background color.

```
 Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

but it shows a small rectangle in bottom-left corner. it isn't in full screen.
i am new in kivy.
help me out guys, please. i want the rectangle that cover whole screen.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind **pos** and **size** so that every change will change the canvas drawing

```
... #inside  __init__
def draw_background(widget, prop):
    with widget.canvas:
        Color(rgba=[1,0,0,1])
        Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
self.bind(size=draw_background)
self.bind(pos=draw_background)
...
```

Comment: You really don't actually. It fully depends on what you're attempting to do. If you're working with absolute fixed sizes than you can set it the size using something other than self.size otherwise as Yoav has pointed out every time you change the window size it won't scale properly.